# How to use columns in rows using readline of python

Tags: python, readline

I have a big data, and I am trying to do some analysis on specific columns of it.
I know the number of rows (around 2000), but the number of columns of it can be varied for each row.
for opening the file and do analysis on it, I used:

```
a=np.loadtxt("file.csv")
```

And I got this error:

ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

It happens because of having different columns.

So I tried to read the file using readline(). The point is that in readline, I do not know how to change the string into integer in a way that I can use columns.
one example of the file is like this:

```
0 12 123 53.884 -20
156 1234 1 -123 543 4924 0 -0.3
```

The numbers are separated by space, the number of columns are varied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read row as string. Then split row by blank.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solution if it helped you